upgrade spring5 to spring6.1 for springboot2 project
project need upgrade to spring6.1 which need httpclient5,
but project using SendGrid  API only support httpclient4.
Anyone has good advice? thanks in advance.
`
public Response getResponse(CloseableHttpResponse response) throws IOException { 
//as upgraded to spring6.1, param response is using httpclient5 API
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new SendGridResponseHandler(); 
    String responseBody = handler.handleResponse(response); //SendGrid  API only support param is httpclient4's CloseableHttpResponse   
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Header h : headers) {
        responseHeaders.put(h.getName(), h.getValue());
    }

    return new Response(statusCode, responseBody, responseHeaders);
}`

My final target is upgrade spring5 to spring6.1
